# Swift 3 How to declare an assignment operator on custom class

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift3

I would like to declare an assignment operator on my custom class CGFloat01 so that I can use it like so:

```
var a:CGFloat01
var b:CGFloat

a = b
```

I tried the following, but it doesn't compile:

```
func = (lhs:CGFloat01, rhs:CGFloat) -> CGFloat01 {
    lhs.value = rhs
    return lhs
}
```

Comment: God I hate implicit behaviour like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't

From the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html)

> It is not possible to overload the default assignment operator (=). Only the compound assignment operators can be overloaded. Similarly, the ternary conditional operator (a ? b : c) cannot be overloaded.

Comment: well ... that explains it

Comment: @andrewz most languages don't trust you with this power, as far as I know C++ is the only one that does.